# What does it mean to run gedit in standalone mode?

Tags: gedit, command-line, documentation

I was reading [`man gedit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gedit), when I stumbled upon this:

```
-s, --standalone
              Run gedit in standalone mode.
```

The [official `gedit` documentation on this subject](http://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/NewSingleInstance) did not make me much wiser. So...

- What does `standalone mode` really mean?
- When would I need this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking it at the source, -s makes gedit always start a new process and a new window, rather than adding a tab to an existing gedit window that's already running. Useful if you're worried about one window crashing taking down the other. You can do the same thing with gnome-terminal with the "--disable-factory" switch, which *is* useful, as g-t has been known to crash, and take down the processes running in all your tabs and windows with it!

**Edit:** And the docs you linked above point out that it's also useful if you're invoking gedit from a batch file, or from a mail program, etc. - "gedit -s" will create a new process that won't exit until the window is closed, whereas plain "gedit" will return immediately if there's already a gedit process running.